# Fortran Function does not return value to the main program

Tags: fortran

I have called a function `integ` from another function `rter3`. I have printed `integ` values from the `integ` function and it prints legitimate values. But when I print `integ` values at `rter3` function, it prints `0.00` . I have tried all I could to understand why it does that but could not figure out. Please help me out here. Thanks.

```
function rter3(z,c1,nx1,xarray,xlocation,angl3r,gamr,probr,aaa,da1)
    use data
    integer:: z,o,nx1,lc
    double precision:: c1(nx1),w1,w2,rter3,angl3r,gamr,probr(100),aaa,da1,rati2,xarray(nx1),xlocation,div1
    double precision:: variable
    dx=0.1
    rati2=20.0
    !write(*,*) z,o,nx1,xlocation,angl3,gam
    w1=div1(c1(z-1),c1(z),dx)
    w2=div1(c1(z),c1(z+1),dx)
    variable=integ(nx1,c1,xarray,xlocation,dx,angl3r,gamr,probr,aaa,da1,w1,w2)
    rter3=rati2*variable
    write(*,*) "rter3=", rter3, variable, rati2, xlocation, gam, angl3, da1
end function rter3

function integ(nxx,hfield,xfield,loc1,diff,angl3,gam,prob,afield,dprob,ab2,af2)
    implicit none
    integer :: l,nxx,dui,kk,indx,indt
    double precision:: du(101),prob(100),am1,a,ap1,angl3,gam,diff,dprob,integ,function12,afield(100),xfield(nxx)
    double precision:: loc1,loc2,hfield(nxx),am2,ap2,ab2,af2
    !write(*,*) 'test loop', loc1, diff, angl3, gam, dprob

    do kk=1,100
        do l=1,nxx
            if (0.95*xfield(l)>=loc1-afield(kk).and. 1.05*xfield(l)<loc1-afield(kk)) then
                dui=l
                !call exit()
            endif
        enddo
        !dui= loc1-kk
        !write(*,*) "Entered integ", dui
        !write(*,*) dui
        if (dui<=3) then
            dui=3
        endif
        if (dui>= nxx-2) then
            dui=nxx-2
        endif
        am1=hfield(dui-1)
        am2=hfield(dui-2)
        a=hfield(dui)
        ap2=hfield(dui+2)
        ap1=hfield(dui+1)
        du(kk)=abs(prob(kk)*(function12(am2,am1,ap1,ap2,diff,angl3,gam,ab2,af2))*dprob)
    enddo

    integ=sum(du)
    write(*,*) "integration value=", integ, nxx, loc1, diff, angl3, gam, dprob
end function integ
```

So, those are the individual functions for your reference. Please let me know if you feel something is wrong. The whole code is very big but if you feel you need to see it, I shall attach it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

How does the rter3 function "know" the interface of the integ function?    Are both in the same module?  If not, perhaps rter3 doesn't know the interface and is using implicit typing.   Since you didn't use "implicit none" in rter3 it might do that, in which case the bits of integ would be interpreted as an integer, while they are supposed to be interpreted as double precision -- the value would appear incorrectly.   My suggestions: always place your procedures in a module.  Then you are OK with procedues in the same module ... the compiler can check argument consistency.   If you call a subroutine or function from a main program or another module, "use" the module to obtain the argument checking.  Use "implicit none".  In case you forget to include implicit none in your source code, additionally use the compiler option that does the same thing (e.g., -fimplicit-none for gfortran).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Yes, you are correct and I originally had placed all the procedures(rter3 and integ, both being double precision) in the module called "data" which has been used in the function rter3. I have also used implicit none in the source code. Can you suggest me anything else that I can do? Thanks again.

Comment: Hey. I had instead defined 'double precision:: integ' in rter3 and it worked!. Somehow the module did not work. Thanks a lot for that idea.

Comment: Are you compiling things in the necessary order?  That is something that tends not be explained because it is outside of the language standard.  If the module and main program are in separate files, the module file typically must be before the main program in the compile command.  If the source code is in one file, the module must precede any routines that use it.